# How to define the Context for a ModelSetup

Tags: moryx

The Documentation of the [Moryx-Plattform](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform) provides an example for a hardcoded model setup in [here](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/docs/tutorials/DataModel/ModelSetups.md), which I copied below

```cs
[ModelSetup(typeof(EmployeeContext))]
public class HardCodedSetup : IModelSetup
{
    public int SortOrder => 1;
    public string Name => "Sample";
    public string Description => "Sample Description";
    public string SupportedFileRegex => string.Empty;
    [...]
}
```

My question now is, how the `EmployeeContext` would look like in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmployeeContext` referes to an EntityFramework `DbContext`, so a database model. If you want to write a setup for products, target `ProductsContext` from `Moryx.Products.Model`.